# Yii CHtml or traditional HTML inputs

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

I've just started coding in Yii2. I am very curious if there are advantages in creating the forms with CHtml rather than using pure HTML.

I've searched the internet, stack overflow and I couldn't find any good answer to this question.

From what I realized using `CHtml::dropDownList` is usefull when you want to populate it from the DB, but are there any other advantanges using other functions that I don't know about?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html

Comment: yii2 don't use CHTML but helper   HTML.

Comment: you should see that in the Yii documentations, why did you post this here? people might down vote you.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I know but I wanted to clearly differentiate the two in the question.

Comment: @Bira, their documentation doesn't answer my question. It doesn't say clearly what the advantages/disadvantages are for using Yii CHtml vs HTML inputs.

Comment: then  ..  i have posted  some personal  consideration .. hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

I'my experience .. the advantage for using helper HTML in Yii2 (or CHtml i yii1)  is related  to the full integreation of the helper with PHP and the variable or the param  used  by yii2 for build in a syntetic way the widget for generate valud HTML code  ..

In php the need  of assign the right param in the right place in frequent and important the helper class  in general and HTML Helper in particular are oriented to this  .. avoding string concatenation and mixin between html and php code  .

Just a sample
In a single line of code you can manage easily  the code for configurate the submit button for create and update with right css class  avoid mixind between code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'),
                 ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Uodate</button>    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```